# Rename all the files in the folder with increasing numbers

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal

I have a folder and inside that folder I have 10-15 files with arbitrary names.
The filenames may include spaces in them. For example: `wWw.page.com  __ (576)_002`.
In a terminal, when I press `w` and then `tab` the file name appears like this: `wWw.page.com\ \ __\ \(576\)_0.txt`.

I want some script that will rename all my files like this `0.txt`, `1.txt`, `2.txt` and so on.

My problem is: `wWw.page.com  __ (576)_002.txt file not found`.

```
index=0;
for i in $(ls *.txt)
do
    cp "${i}"  $index".txt" 
done
```

Comment: `perl -e'rename $_, $i++.q(.txt) while(<*.txt>)'`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Instead of `ls` try to `glob`:

```
index=0;
for name in *.txt
do
    cp "${name}" "${index}.txt"
    index=$((index+1))
done
```

Comment: And you don't *need* the inner `$` (`index=$((index+1))`)

Comment: Yep, and why this works: on command substitution, bash will break the command output according to `IFS` -- not so with a glob.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker I rarely write scrips. Is there a beter way to increment index ?

Comment: @cnicutar, first, like I said in parenthesis. Or, you can just do `((++index))`

Comment: Just drop the `$` in index calculation: `index=$((index+1))`. In arithmetic context (`$((...))`), barewords are variable references.

Comment: naturally, this nitpicking over incrementing index has nothing to do with the breaking problem :)

Comment: can we use this `index=$[index+1]` ..?

Comment: You could use `cp "$name" "$((i++)).txt"` and do away with the following line altogether.

Comment: Should also note that `cp` will keep the original files in the folder, `mv` - wouldn't